# October CMS installation report SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] ACCESS DENIED FOR USER 'ROOT'@'LOCALHOST' (USING PASSWORD: NO)

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, octobercms

I set up a personal web server and I'm tryng to install October CMS on it, but during "Building configuration files" the installere return me this error.
The user I used to access the database is not the root and, by the way, the root user have a password...

What's the problem here?

EDIT: Solved by installing October without project or plugin

Comment: have you mention other user while installation ?

Comment: I solved installing October without any project or plugin

Comment: ok problem solve or still any issue ?

Comment: ok nice to here that your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

change app/config.php 'host'      => '127.0.0.1',